# Cyclic Dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am having this error...I kind of know what it mean but I can't figure how to go about it. Someone willing to help me out? Thanks.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  securityConfig (field private ro.sda.finalproject.service.UserService ro.sda.finalproject.config.security.SecurityConfig.userService)
↑     ↓
|  userService defined in file [D:\Proiect-Final\target\classes\ro\sda\finalproject\service\UserService.class]
└─────┘

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4TvU.png)
Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.

Process finished with exit code 0

See below the two classes:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import ro.sda.finalproject.config.security.UserPrincipal;
import ro.sda.finalproject.controller.exception.ResourceAlreadyExistsException;
import ro.sda.finalproject.controller.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import ro.sda.finalproject.dto.UserDto;
import ro.sda.finalproject.enums.RoleType;
import ro.sda.finalproject.mapper.UserMapper;
import ro.sda.finalproject.model.Role;
import ro.sda.finalproject.model.User;
import ro.sda.finalproject.repository.RoleRepository;
import ro.sda.finalproject.repository.UserRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private UserMapper userMapper;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository,
                       RoleRepository roleRepository,
                       UserMapper userMapper,
                       PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(UserDto userDto) {
        log.info("save user {}", userDto);

        String email = userDto.getEmail();
        userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .map(existingUser -> {
                    log.error("user with email {} already exists", email);
                    throw new ResourceAlreadyExistsException("user with email " + email + " already exists");
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> saveUser(userDto));
    }

    public List<UserDto> findAll() {
        log.info("find users");

        return userRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(user -> userMapper.map(user))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        log.info("find user by email {}", email);

        return userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(email + " not found"));
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .map(user -> {

                    Set<Role> roles = roleRepository.getRoles(user.getUserId());
                    return new UserPrincipal(user, roles);
                })
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(email + " not found"));
    }

    public UserDto findById(Long id) {

        // find by id from repo
        return userRepository.findById(id)
                .map(user -> userMapper.map(user))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("user not found"));
    }

    public void update(UserDto dto) {
        userRepository.findById(dto.getUserId())
                .map(user -> userMapper.update(user, dto))
                .map(updatedUser -> userRepository.save(updatedUser))
                .orElseThrow(() -> {
                    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("user not found");
                });
    }

    public void enable(Long id) {
        log.info("enable user {}", id);

        userRepository.findById(id)
                .map(foundUser -> {
                    foundUser.setEnabled(true);
                    return userRepository.save(foundUser);
                })
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("user not found"));
    }

    public void disable(Long id) {
        log.info("disable user {}", id);

        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByType(RoleType.ADMIN)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("role not found"));
        long enabledAdminsCount = userRepository.findAll().stream()
                .filter(user -> user.isEnabled())
                .filter(user -> user.getRoles().contains(adminRole))
                .count();
        if (enabledAdminsCount > 1) {
            userRepository.findById(id)
                    .map(foundUser -> {
                        foundUser.setEnabled(false);
                        return userRepository.save(foundUser);
                    })
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("user not found"));

        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("can't disable last admin");
        }
    }

    private User saveUser(UserDto userDto) {
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByType(RoleType.USER)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("role not found"));

        // convert user dto to user
        User user = userMapper.map(userDto);
        // encode password
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
        user.addRole(userRole);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        userRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("user not found" + id));
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import ro.sda.finalproject.service.UserService;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                // common
                .antMatchers("/", "/product-photos/**", "/index", "/about", "/contact", "/register/**", "/addToCart", "/login", "/search", "/shoppingCart").permitAll()

                // no authorization needed
                .antMatchers("/home", "/products/**").permitAll()


                // static resources
                .antMatchers("/static/favicon.ico", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()

                // features and permissions
                // TODO: add all features before production
                .antMatchers().hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // add custom login form
        http.formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll());

        // login with email as username
        http.formLogin().usernameParameter("email");

        // after successful login go to page
        // TODO: find a way to load the correct page depending on role
        http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true);

        // after logout go to login
        http.logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll();

        // add a custom access denied handler 404 unauthorized
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/webjars/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(createDaoAuthentication());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider createDaoAuthentication() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return provider;
    }

    // notifies the session registry that the session is destroyed on logout
    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }
}
```

I tried eliminating the dependency one after another without success

Comment: security config depends on user service, user service depends on security config (password encoder only;) ..solution: declare password encoder outside/"above" security config ;)

Comment: alternatively: refactor user service from `@Service` to `@Bean`

Comment: Since the only thing that SecurityConfig needs UserService for is as a UserDetailsService, you could create an independent UserDetailsService. A separate @Service that implements the one method `public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)`

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).